# My program crashes when the button is clicked.. why?

Tags: java, android

[LOGCAT](http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=331691&c=7643541)

```
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at coin.calc.wilson.CoinCalculatorActivity$1.onClick(CoinCalculatorActivity.java:65) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
04-03 20:59:46.189: E/AndroidRuntime(362): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-03 20:59:49.720: I/Process(362): Sending signal. PID: 362 SIG: 9
```

Here is my java code:

```
package coin.calc.wilson;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CoinCalculatorActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button solve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsolve);
    solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) { 
    int td, tc, twenty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime, nickel, penny;
    EditText tdet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdollars);
    EditText tcet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcents);
        try{
            td = Integer.parseInt(tdet.getText().toString());
            tc = Integer.parseInt(tdet.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            td = tc = 0;
        }

    if (td < 0 || tc < 0){
        /* ERROR */
    }
    else{
        if( td == 0 ){
            twenty = ten = five = one = 0;
        }
        else{
            one = td%5;

            if(td >= 20){
                twenty = (td/20)-((td%20)/20);
            }
            else{
                twenty = 0;
            }

            int tda20 = td-(20*twenty);
            if (tda20 >= 10){
                ten = (tda20/10)-((tda20%10)/10);
            }
            else{
                ten = 0;
            }
            int tda10 = tda20-(10*ten);
            if(tda10>=5){
                five = (tda10/5)-((tda10%5)/5);
            }
            else{
                five = 0;
            }
            TextView tv20 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtwenty);
            tv20.setText(twenty);
            TextView tv10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvten);
            tv10.setText(ten);
            TextView tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfive);
            tv5.setText(five);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvone);
            tv1.setText(one);

            }


        if( tc == 0 ){
            quarter = dime = nickel = penny = 0;
        }
        else{
            penny = tc%5;

            if(tc >= 25){
                quarter = (tc/25)-((td%25)/25);
            }
            else{
                quarter = 0;
            }

            int tcaq = tc-(25*quarter);
            if (tcaq >= 10){
                dime = (tcaq/10)-((tcaq%10)/10);
            }
            else{
                dime = 0;
            }
            int tcad = tcaq-(10*ten);
            if(tcad>=5){
                nickel = (tcad/5)-((tcad%5)/5);
            }
            else{
                nickel = 0;
            }
            TextView tvq = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvquarter);
            tvq.setText(quarter);
            TextView tvd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdime);
            tvd.setText(dime);
            TextView tvn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvnickel);
            tvn.setText(nickel);
            TextView tvp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvpenny);
            tvp.setText(penny);

            }
}
}});}
}
```

and here is the xml:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etdollars"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dollars"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etcents"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cents"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsolve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Solve!" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8.75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/twenty" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtwenty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cquarter" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvquarter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8.75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ten" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvten"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cdime" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8.75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/five" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvfive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cnickel" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnickel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8.75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cpenny" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvpenny"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

If it helps, i think the error MAY have something to do with resources i am using (eight jpgs), but i'm not sure. The program runs cleanly up until the OnClickListener is activated. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Sorry, posting ALL code here, logcat somewhere else just to point you on the line 65 is a waste of our time! Please reduce the code, read the stacktrace and try to solve it before posting everything here... at least the next time...

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Use it to *debug* your code.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I will, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is here (and in another lines like that):

```
tv20.setText(twenty);
```

`twenty` is int and should be String (I suppose that you want to show the number in the textview):

```
tv20.setText(String.valueOf(twenty));
```

EDIT:

All this variables have the same error

`int td, tc, twenty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime, nickel, penny;`

Comment: `String.valueOf(twenty)` is kinda ugly. Use `""+twenty` instead :)

Comment: Veto! If you use + you create an empty string, concatening the interger to it and store it as a new String while throwing away the empty one. Waste of object creation and memory...

Answer (score 1):

You have a small but heavy mistake:

If you try to put a number/integer into a TextView, you need to cast it to a String first. If you don't do that, Android things you reference to an internal id like `R.string.mynumber` and that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the two following lines right underneath `Button solve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsolve);` and before `solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`

```
EditText tdet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etdollars);
EditText tcet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcents);
```